# How to create bean for spring data jpa repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Custom, Long> {}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyServiceInterface {
 
 private final MyRepository repository;
}
```

I use test configuration with instructions for bean construction for testing.
How to create `@Bean` for `MyRepository interface`?

```java
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.app")
public class TestBeans {

 @Bean 
 MyServiceInterface getMyService() {
  return new MyServiceImpl(getMyRepository()); 
 }

 @Bean 
 MyRepository getMyRepository() {
  return null; // what should be here?
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you can just autowire the repository, can't you?

Comment: also thinking about this. Or maybe there is other solution?

Comment: @IljaTarasovs This is the one and only correct way. Why would you need another solution?

Comment: yes, agree with all of you. Will use `@Autowired`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use @Autowire, spring will take care of bean creation if you had given @Repository on JPA interface.

Comment: agree with your commnet

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `@Repository` you noticed that this annotation is a stereotype of `@Component`. So when you use annotation `@Repository` this class will be treat as a bean (of course, if you enable jpa repositories).

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Repository {
   ...
}
```

So if you want inject you repository into your bean, you can do like this:

```
 @Bean 
 MyServiceInterface getMyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
  return new MyServiceImpl(myRepository); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot 3.0.6

Three conditions must be met (regardeless if its for tests or for the main code):

1. The repository must have the @Repository annotation
2. The class that uses the autowired member or constructor param must be a spring bean
3. JpaRepositories must be enabled (annotate "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.app")" somewhere in your configuration class)

It's not needed to have an extra "Bean declaration" for your repository interface. The @Repository and the @EnableJpaRepositories annotations are enough.